# SQL in Access, subquery pairing issue

Tags: sql, ms-access, subquery

I wrote an SQL statement in Access that looks for rows of data with the same value in their 'Code' column and then looks at those rows with the same 'Code' value and finds rows with opposite 'Money Amt' column values (for example one row would have a value of 200 and another would have -200) a column labeled line is then populated with the number '999' when pairs of these opposite values with the same code are found.

The problem is that some of my rows are pairing in odd numbered groups instead of by pairs of 2. I want there to be a 1:1 relationship for the opposing values so that they essentially negate each other.

Here is the code I used to get the result so far.

```
UPDATE  [Actual Debt]
SET LineItem = 999
WHERE EXISTS
    (SELECT * FROM  [Actual Debt] as ad2 
    WHERE ad2.Code = [Actual Debt].Code 
    AND ad2.[Money Amt] = - [Actual Debt].[Money Amt]);
```

[image]

In the picture you can see that in the first 4 rows the code populated 2 pairs of opposing 'Money Amt' values as intended. But, in the bottom 3 rows there should have only been 1 pair of '999', but instead it has populated an odd number of rows.

How do I get the subquery to only populate the Line field for opposing pairs.

[Image from before I put in the current code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kgDS4.png)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I think you should show the before table as well.  The 3 rows on the bottom makes pefect sense assuming there were two records with `+0.9` and one record with `-0.9`.

Comment: If you have duplicates, this is going to be very hard to do in an MS Access query.  I might suggest that you just do this in an application.  Other databases have functionality that make this possible in a single query.

Comment: I added the before. Is there a way to write the code so that it would only do pairs of 2?

Comment: Gordon, what application or database would you suggest, and would I be able to migrate it back over to Access after?

Comment: Do you have any other columns in this table that we can use to link these pairs together?

Comment: Also, is there not another table linked to this table that we can use to group these transactions together?

Answer (score 0):

Now Gordon I do believe this can be done in MS Access.  You can do just about everything in Access that you can do in other database its just a matter of figuring out the how.  However in this particular case there seems to be a problem with the underlying data that is causing the current issue and without seeing the entire source table it is very hard to determine what that error is.  Still I would venture to guess that if you ran your sub-Query by itself (as I show below) that you would get the data as I show below.  Try running just the SELECT part of your query and see what you get.

```
SELECT *
  FROM ActualDebt AS Ad2

 WHERE Ad2.Code = ActualDebt.Code
   AND Ad2.MoneyAmt = ((-1) * ActualDebt.MoneyAmt);
```

Most likely the Query Results are as follows based on what I see in your table

```
Code | MoneyAmt
 MHT     .3
 MHT     .3
 MHT     -.3
 MHT     -.3
 RLO     .4
 RLO     .6
 MQR     .9
 MQR     -.9
 MQR     .9
```

So Gordon if what I have outlined above, is the issue, then yes you will need to provide more information in order for a solution to be determine because programmatically right now there would be no way to differentiate between the first MQR .9 and the other MQR .9 -- which seems to be the source of the issue

I will keep an eye on this post and if you edit your question then I will edit this answer to help.